# Close WinSCP window opened by a PowerShell script when finished

Tags: powershell, winscp

I wrote a script that loops over a folder and converts files using WinSCP

```
WinSCP.exe /keygen $filePath /output=$filePathdest
```

The script works but leaves several WinSCP windows open stating what it completed it's task. I would like to suppress this or force PowerShell to close all of its children when finished. Is this possible?

Comment: Executing `WinSCP` in console (scripting) mode using parameter `/console` should set `errorlevel` (or `$LastExitCode` in powershell) without visual feedback (window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`winscp.com` instead of `winscp.exe`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables).

```
winscp.com /keygen $filePath /output=$filePathdest
```

The `winscp.com` is a console application with the same functionality as `winscp.exe`. Being a console application it inherits the console from PowerShell and does not open its own. It also does not wait for key press when done.

Comment: I never had this problem in Linux, just sayin' lol ... can't I wait X seconds at the end of the script and call everything that script launched / owns ?

Comment: Why? Why don't you do what I have proposed in my answer?

Comment: I'm not satisfied only in the sense that the script should have the ultimate control.. That is how I would do it in Linux Shell

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The problem is that you have called a GUI application (`winscp.exe`) from a script. While you should have used console/command-line application (`winscp.com`), so that everything stays in the same console window.

Comment: Well you should be able to call a command or whatever and terminate it from the script. I do it in Linux all the time.